# Can't Fix React Dark Mode Flashing

Tags: reactjs, local-storage, darkmode, flashing

I am facing a frustrating issue with implementing dark mode into my React application.
The application reads from `localStorage` and applies the theme preferred by the user (this is all done by [`use-dark-mode`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-dark-mode)).
Unfortunately, everytime the user opens the page, the default theme flashes before dark mode is enabled.

Now, I've looked around the internet and found out, that simply placing specific code (as seen [here](https://github.com/donavon/use-dark-mode/blob/develop/noflash.js.txt)) in a `<script>` tag just after `<body>` resolves the issue.

Problem is, nothing seems to fix this unpleasant flash and it occurs across all browsers. I've tried moving the script inside the `<head>` tag and even running it with `window.onload`, but nothing seemed to work.

Has anyone experienced a problem like this? What's the best approach to fix this flash?
Thanks a lot in advance!

Here's a link to the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/wgumenyuk/react-dark-mode-flashing).
*Note: I'm not using any server-side rendering.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the fix is really easy.
In your `index.html` add a bit of style inside the `<head>` tag.

```html
<style type="text/css">
  body.light-mode {
    background-color: #F9FAFC;
  }

  body.dark-mode {
    background-color: #1A1A1A;
  }
</style>
```